# how do i redirect using ajax and php together?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to redirect my users from the login page to the profile. I am using ajax to validate the form but when I login successfully, it displays the profile page on top of the index page. how do I redirect to the profile page in a new page?

Index. php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Yahbang</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#signup-form").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var first = $("#signup-first").val();
                var last = $("#signup-last").val();
                var email = $("#signup-email").val();
                var pwd = $("#signup-pwd").val();
                var submit = $("#signup-submit").val();
                $(".signup-message").load("include/signup.inc.php", {
                    first: first,
                    last: last,
                    email: email,
                    pwd: pwd,
                    submit: submit
                });
            });
        });

            $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#login-form").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var email = $("#login-email").val();
                var pwd = $("#login-pwd").val();
                var submit = $("#login-submit").val();
                $(".login-message").load("include/login.inc.php", {
                    email: email,
                    pwd: pwd,
                    submit: submit
                });
            });
        });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<header>

    <div class="header_index">
            <div class="headerlogo">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php">Yahbang</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>


                <form id="login-form" class="loginform" action='include/login.inc.php' method='POST'>
                        <input  id="login-email" type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email'>
                        <input  id="login-pwd" type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'>
                        <p><a href="forgotpassword.php">Forgot Password</a></p>
                        <button id="login-submit" type='submit'>Login</button>
                        <p class="login-message"></p>
                    </form>



</header>


                <form id="signup-form" class="signup" action='include/signup.inc.php' method='POST'>
                    <input id="signup-first" type='text' name='first' placeholder='First Name'><br>
                    <input id="signup-last" type='text' name='last' placeholder='Last Name'><br>
                    <input id="signup-email" type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email'><br>
                    <input id="signup-pwd" type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'><br>
                    <button id="signup-submit" type='submit'>Sign Up</button>
                    <p class="signup-message"></p>
                </form>





<footer>
    <div class="footer_index">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="TermsofUse.php">Terms of Use</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../dbh.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$hash_pwd = $row['pwd'];
$hash = password_verify($pwd, $hash_pwd);

    $errorEmpty = false;
    $errorEmail = false;

if ($hash == 0) {
    echo "<span class='login-error'>Your Email or password is incorrect!</span>";
    $errorEmpty = true;

} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND pwd='$hash_pwd'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


    if (!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<span class='login-error'>Your Email or password is incorrect!</span>";
        $errorEmpty = true;
    } 

else {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            header("Location: ../profile.php");
}
}

}

?>



<script> 
$("#login-email, #login-pwd").removeClass("input-error");

    var errorEmpty = "<?php echo $errorEmpty; ?>";
    var errorEmail = "<?php echo $errorEmail; ?>";

 if (errorEmpty == true) {
  $("#login-email, #login-pwd").addClass("input-error");
 }

 if (errorEmail == true) {
  $("#login-email").addClass("input-error");
 } 

 if (errorEmpty == false && errorEmail == false) {
  $("#login-email, #login-pwd").val("");
}

 </script>
```

Comment: First ajax doesn't reload pages, Second you have two ready functions in your script in your "Index.php" Why this?

Comment: I know that ajax doesn't reload pages. that's the purpose of ajax, to refresh data without reloading the page. the question i'm asking is how to redirect to another file and not have it load on top of my current file in the same page. Please advise on what I should do. I am currently trying to learn.

Comment: If you want to use ajax to validate the login, you should wait for the ajax response and then change the page. One way to do this is through javascript window.location = ""Location: ../profile.php";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider multiple note to do this right.

**Gathering All Respond In An Array**
You should create an array and put the data you want to respond there. eg:

```
$respond = array(
    'status'   => false,
    'message'  => 'Message Seen By User',
    'redirect' => 'Destination URL'
);
```

Whenever you process request you should change these indexes. for example if authentication was successful change `status` to `true` and `redirect` to `destination url` and etc. Eventually when you process everything do not user any `header` nor `echo`, at the end convert array to json and echo it:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

**Refactor Your JS**
Instead of using multiple $(document).ready use this for each event you want. eg:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.login-message', function(){
    //Write Event Handling Here
});
```

**Using JQuery AJAX**
Instead of load use ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url/to/php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {email: email, pwd: pwd, submit: submit},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(respond){
        if(!respond.status)
        {
            //Show respond.message to user
        }
        else
            Window.Location.href = respond.redirect;
    }
});
```

**Or With JQuery Load**
Using load for these kind of request is not appropriate enough, but:

```
$(".login-message").load("include/login.inc.php", {email: email, pwd: pwd, submit: submit}, function(response, status, xhr){
    respond = JSON.parse(response);
    if(!respond.status)
    {
        //Show respond.message to user
    }
    else
        Window.Location.href = respond.redirect;
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help. i'm still learning and this is so valuable to me. thank you.

Comment: sorry for one final question. You had said put echo json_encode($response); at the end.  should that be at the end of the array or after the entire process of valditating form?

Comment: When you don't have anything else to check, where there wont be any other change to `$response`